# X-axis scaling from number value to time in C#

Tags: c#

I have a line graph where my x-axis shows ticks every 3000 data points. The frequency that I am working with is 10 Hz meaning 3000 data points translates to 3000/10 (300 seconds). Ultimately I would want to show it in minutes, so it should show 300/60 (5 minutes), 10, 15, 20, 25, and so on. Right now I am trying to find it on the properties of the chart but can't find it.

[image]

Comment: What chart is this? What environment (WPF, WinForms, ASP.NET ) ?

Comment: This is my first time using Visual Studio 2010 C#, I just downloaded it and working with the default chart that comes with the toolbox. Not sure if that answers your question

Comment: Are you building a web site or a desktop application?

Comment: Windows Form Application

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
var ticks = 3000;
var seconds = ticks / 10;
var minutes = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds).TotalMinutes;
```

Comment: How would I incorporate in to my object "chart1"  Any method/function that I need to call to adjust the ticks ratio and then re-label accordingly

Comment: This would be the way to adjust the source data before it was applied to the graph. You should probably use LINQ and wrap this in a `Select` statement.